# Java script name value pairs storage in unsorted way

Tags: javascript

I am new to java script.

There is an existing javascript code that reads a JSON document and creates XML fine. But the xml document does not have the elements in the same order as that is in the JSON document.
How to achive this? Currently the java script uses tree. I used list, hash but in vain.
Not sure as which javascript data structure to use so that it will **not** store data in a sorted order/alphabetical order.
Any code example is highly appreciated.

```
JSON:
{
  "data:xxData": {
    "xyz": "value",
    "abc": "order",

  }
}
```

Resultant XML:

```
<data:xxData>
    <abc>order</abc>
    <xyz>value</xyz>
</data:xxData>
```

Expected correct XML:

```
 <data:xxData>
    <xyz>value</xyz>
    <abc>order</abc>
 </data:xxData>
```

Thanks in advance.

Here is the code:

I call the writeXML by passing it the JSON string.

```
    XML.ObjTree.prototype.writeXML = function ( tree ) {
        var xml = this.hash_to_xml( null, tree );
        return this.xmlDecl + xml;
    };


    XML.ObjTree.prototype.hash_to_xml = function ( name, tree ) {
        var elem = [];
        var attr = [];
        for( var key in tree ) {
            print("key: "+ key+'\n')
            //print("tree: "+ tree[key]+'\n')
            if ( ! tree.hasOwnProperty(key) ) continue;
            var val = tree[key];
            if ( key.charAt(0) != this.attr_prefix ) {
                if ( typeof(val) == "undefined" || val == null ) {
                    elem[elem.length] = "<"+key+" />";
                } else if ( typeof(val) == "object" && val.constructor == Array ) {
                    elem[elem.length] = this.array_to_xml( key, val );
                } else if ( typeof(val) == "object" ) {
                    elem[elem.length] = this.hash_to_xml( key, val );
                } else {
                    elem[elem.length] = this.scalar_to_xml( key, val );
                }
            } else {
                attr[attr.length] = " "+(key.substring(1))+'="'+(this.xml_escape( val ))+'"';
            }
        }
        var jattr = attr.join("");
        var jelem = elem.join("");
        if ( typeof(name) == "undefined" || name == null ) {
            // no tag
        } else if ( elem.length > 0 ) {
            if ( jelem.match( /\n/ )) {
                jelem = "<"+name+jattr+">\n"+jelem+"</"+name+">\n";
            } else {
                jelem = "<"+name+jattr+">"  +jelem+"</"+name+">\n";
            }
        } else {
            jelem = "<"+name+jattr+" />\n";
        }
        return jelem;
    };


XML.ObjTree.prototype.array_to_xml = function ( name, array ) {
    var out = [];
    for( var i=0; i<array.length; i++ ) {
        var val = array[i];
        if ( typeof(val) == "undefined" || val == null ) {
            out[out.length] = "<"+name+" />";
        } else if ( typeof(val) == "object" && val.constructor == Array ) {
            out[out.length] = this.array_to_xml( name, val );
        } else if ( typeof(val) == "object" ) {
            out[out.length] = this.hash_to_xml( name, val );
        } else {
            out[out.length] = this.scalar_to_xml( name, val );
        }
    }
    return out.join("");
};

//  method: scalar_to_xml( tagName, text )

XML.ObjTree.prototype.scalar_to_xml = function ( name, text ) {
    if ( name == "#text" ) {
        return this.xml_escape(text);
    } else {
        return "<"+name+">"+this.xml_escape(text)+"</"+name+">\n";
    }
};

//  method: xml_escape( text )

XML.ObjTree.prototype.xml_escape = function ( text ) {
    return (text + '').replace(/&/g,'&amp;').replace(/</g,'&lt;').replace(/>/g,'&gt;').replace(/"/g,'&quot;');
};
```

Comment: what is this "existing javascript code" that you used?  Please provide this code so we can fix it.

Comment: There's no order in JSON objects. If you need any kind of order, you need to build it and keep somewhere (e.g. in array) yourself.

Comment: I updated my original post with the code. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
JSON:
{
  "data:xxData": [
     { "xyz": "value" },
     { "abc": "order" }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: (I can't tell from your code because you did not put in the source for array_to_xml()

Comment: I added array_to_xml() to the original post. I print out the tree content - it has the data BUT NOT IN THE SAME ORDER as it is in JSON string. Also the json that you mentioned is not what I want. Your Json related output is coming as below but I want ALL  elements to be enclosed by a SINGLE data:xxData.                     Output with your JSON:  <data:xxData> <xyz>value</xyz> </data:xxData> <data:xxData> <abc>order</abc> </data:xxData>–  Dev 35 mins ago

Comment: @Dev - I see that.  I don't see any way to generate this xml with this conversion code since it adds the parent around every element of an array.  This is not how I would convert to xml.